# Angularjs : tooltip is not working when using with ng-model in select-option (select2 plugin also used)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I am trying to somehow get the description of all the options in the drop down, But when I am trying to use tooltip/uib-tooltip the data is not coming but if I am not using the ng-model the mouse hover thing works fine for me. So can anyone tell me what is the problem ? and solution for it

code is :

```
<div class="col-md-10">
  <select
    ui-select2="multiSelect2Options" multiple
    ng-model="order.items" placeholder="Select Item" tooltip="some data">
    <option ng-repeat="item in list_items | orderBy:'toString()' track by $index " value="[[item]]" title="Tooltip">[[item]]</option>
  </select>
<div>
```

I am also using the select2 plugin and so I also tried to do it using directive but that is also not working for me.

Directive Code is :

```
directive('toolTipDirective',[ function () {
  return{
    restrict : 'E',
    link: function(scope){
        $(".select2-container").tooltip({
            title: function() {
                //console.log("Inside Directive");
                return $(this).prev().attr("title");
            },
            placement: "auto",
            //container: 'body'
        });
      }
 };
}])
```

Html code is :

```
<div class="col-md-10">
  <select
    ui-select2="multiSelect2Options" multiple tool-tip-directive
    ng-model="order.items" placeholder="Select Item">
    <option ng-repeat="item in list_items | orderBy:'toString()' track by $index " value="[[item]]" title="Tooltip">[[item]]</option>
```

I also tried using uib-tooltip, mouseenter too.I am unable to understand what is the problem with my approaches.Kindly Help.

Comment: why don't use `ui-bootstrap` for having `tooltip`

Comment: @PankajParkar Tried using that too. It's working when ng-model is not added but as soon as I add ng-model It stops working.

Comment: I have finally found the cause behind this. It has hierarchy and we can't simply apply tooltip in this.